# Как установить два интерпретатора Python для разных IDE?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Раньше использовал *Jupyter Notebook*, а теперь перехожу на *Visual Studio Code*, который автоматически подключается к интерпретатору *Anaconda*, и в результате появляются проблемы с установкой библиотек и запуском кода. Как настроить VSC так, чтобы он и *Anaconda* были независимы друг от друга?